# Change, add, remove content to iframe that contains other domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe that looks like this:

```
<iframe id="feed" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="http://foo.com/bar"></iframe>
```

I want to change styles, remove and add elements to the iframe

I tried using this:

```
function iframeRef(frameRef) {
            return frameRef.contentWindow ? frameRef.contentWindow.document : frameRef.contentDocument
}
var inside = iframeRef(document.getElementById('feed'));
var elem = inside.createElement('p');
elem.style.zIndex = '2';
elem.style.position = 'absolute';
elem.innerHTML = 'TEXT';
inside.body.appendChild(elem);
```

But it doesn't work, how can I manipulate the DOM from the iframe?

Comment: You can't change the DOM of other domains for security reasons.

Comment: There is no (simple) way to do this. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/364997/983914

Comment: Isn't there a way to copy the DOM from that domain and change the copy?

Comment: JavaScript won't let you access the source of the page in the iFrame, so you can't copy it in order to edit the copy.

Comment: CORS access will have to be allowed on the `contentDocument` page.